# to match part of a string and type the full string out of a given sentence consisting of charater strings

Tags: regex, string

I have a file list.txt which has the path to certain files like :

```
Desktop/28_dec/script/sign_145/check/sig4n_120/mu_30 ;
Desktop/28_dec/run_1/run_12/sign_145/check/sig4n_120/mu_30 ;
Desktop/14_feb/eps_14/run14//sign_145/check/sig4n_120/mu_30 
Desktop/28_dec_2013/eps3_1200/eps_nano_20/sign_130/sign_145/check/sig4n_120/mu_30
```

and so on. The pattern is quite random. In each line,  have to note down three things out the full path in three columns ;

1. the string having 'sig4n_' for ex:: sig4n_130
2. the string having 'sign_'
3. the string having 'mu_',

One way I know is that using split command where the separator will be '/', and then comparing part of the string. I tried to write the script , but my script is showing errors.
I did the following in Linux:

```
z =Desktop/28_feb/eps3_1200/sign_200/sig4n_120/mu_10 ; 
awk '{split($z,arr,"/")}' > data.dat
```

then it was showing the error "`unexpected token '('`" .

I also tried writing

```
z='list.txt' ; 
awk '{split($0,arr,"/")}' list.txt
```

Thanks for going through my question.

Comment: "My script is showing errors". Could you show the script, and the errors? What language is this?

Comment: Ya sure,actually I was trying to use script command using awk, which is as follows :          awk '{split($z,arr,"/")}' list.txt but it is either sometimes showing error as " unexpected token '('" OR not giving any output. I am working on linux OS.

Comment: Can you edit your _whole_ script into the question - because your one line doesn't show me what the value of `$z` is, for example. And reading code in a comment is hard.

Comment: ok my command was like this ; z =Desktop/28_feb/eps3_1200/sign_200/sig4n_120/mu_10 ; awk '{split($z,arr,"/")}' > data.dat   then it was showing the error "unexpected token '(' . I also tried writing      z='list.txt' ; awk '{split($z,arr,"/")}' list.txt, but then no output at all

Answer (score 0):

Still not quite clear what you are doing - the code you gave makes no sense.

A simple solution to your problem is

```
sed -e 's/.*\(sign_...\).*\(sig4n_...\).*\(mu_..\).*$/\1 \2 \3/' list.txt
```

Output (for your input file):

```
sign_145 sig4n_120 mu_30
sign_145 sig4n_120 mu_30
sign_145 sig4n_120 mu_30
sign_145 sig4n_120 mu_30
```

this assumes that all three items (`sign`, `sig4n`, and `mu`) are present and formatted with a certain number of digits. You can probably figure it out from here.

Comment: Thanks for responding,  But that is not working here. I have in my list.text file, a text string : > Desktop/mubeena/28_dec_epsn_1200/sig4n_120/sign_120/mu_80 and after using your command, the result is > Desktop/mubeena/28_dec_epsn_1200/sig4n_120/sign_120/mu_80 , just same as the original text.  Yes in my file, the number of characters in the strings which I want and which are in between "/", is fixed. I dont know why I am not getting the output here which you have got. I want the one which you have got.

Comment: Dear, If I use the previous input which I posted originally, ya I am getting the same output as yours, But when I modified my file to test as in the above comment, Desktop/mubeena/28_dec_epsn_1200/sig4n_120/sign_120/mu_80 in the list.txt file, I am not getting it.

Comment: Ya I got the error, your command works only when the sequence sign_...,sig4n...,mu_.. is maintained. And thats working for my data as of now. Thank you very much for helping me.